# How do I get pyaudio 0.2.9 installed on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, python3

I can't find a PPA, and pyaudio 0.2.7 is what is shipped

Answer (score 6):

This is an issue with `pip`... Somehow it still doesn't install all the dependancies yet

```
sudo apt purge python3-pyaudio
sudo apt install portaudio19-dev python-all-dev
sudo pip3 install pyaudio==0.2.9 --upgrade
```

Comment: I only needed to install `portaudio19-dev` and `python3.7-dev` in order to successfully install `pyaudio`.

Comment: THIS WORKED FOR ME :)