# Cannot install pyaudio 0.2.9 in ubuntu 16.04. How can I install it?

Tags: python

Commands:

```
sudo apt purge python3-pyaudio
sudo apt install portaudio19-dev python-all-dev
sudo pip3 install pyaudio==0.2.9 --upgrade
```

Output of `sudo pip3 install pyaudio==0.2.9 --upgrade`:

```
The directory '/home/soumya/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/soumya/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pyaudio==0.2.9
  Downloading PyAudio-0.2.9.tar.gz (289kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 296kB 360kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-qatjpaq3/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o2fcw5ir-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:28:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-qatjpaq3/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o2fcw5ir-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-qatjpaq3/pyaudio/
```

Comment: Try this `sudo -H pip3 install pyaudio==0.2.9 --upgrade`

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023131/cannot-install-pyaudio-gcc-error https://askubuntu.com/questions/915227/how-do-i-get-pyaudio-0-2-9-installed-on-ubuntu-16-04 will fix

Comment: Already tried above links. Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I believe `pip` tries to avoid changing certain directory permissions to `root` hence the warning. Use the command below instead so the `/home` is always set to yours:

```
sudo -H pip3 install pyaudio==0.2.9 --upgrade
```

Comment: After running the above command I get this


x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:28:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    
    -------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of PyAudio